# Don't let IE select and copy table rows that are hidden using jQuery .hide()

Tags: jquery, visibility

I have a jQuery instant search bar on top of a data table. All records matching the search condition will be visible `$(row).show()`; and the rest are hidden `$(row).hide()`.

Problem:

After a search, I use the mice to select / copy the list of rows from search result and paste them into Excel. The "hidden" records also get pasted.

I tried:

`$(row).css('visibility','collapse');` instead of `hide()` -- doesn't work in IE (Row does't collapse)

How do I get "visibility:collapse" work in IE? Or is there a different workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to hide the non-visible elements from IE/Windows, I'd suggest having a results `table`, and cloning the results of your search to that `table`, and hiding the other. This way the only results available to be selected are the ones that you want to be selected.

Comment: The big deal is to avoid changing the jQuery which I copied from somewhere else (because I dont really know jQuery) and also, the search executes on each keypress event, would that be very hard to do with "copying result to another table"?

Comment: Well, here's a **[proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ccZDb/1/)**. I'd suggest, if there are no 'better' answers that you might want to ask a question about how to achieve an alternate, whether the one I suggested or another, solution to your problem. We can definitely help you with code... =)

Comment: Thank you so much for the sample code~! I tried it with my table, however it is a bit slow (i have over 100 row of records, each one has 6 columns) But thanks anyway!