# Html and Internet Explorer: How to avoid hidden elements to be copied/pasted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've a TABLE, in a HTML5 document.

I've a view selector who hide/show some rows, using jQuery `hide()` and `show()`.

When user select the table (programmatically, using a 'select all' button, see below for the code), and then copy/paste into, for example, Word or Outlook email, the behaviour is different from FF and IE.

- FF: doesn't copy elements with `style='display: none;'`. It's desired and expected behaviour
- IE: copy ALL, and paste ALL, so my visual 'trick' is then useless for IE users.

I add my `selectAll` function. Simply expect a selector and select all the text inside it. It's something I copy/pasted from the jQuery forum.

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    // console.log(this, element);
    if (typeof element == 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
```

**How can I select only visible elements ? Or... is there any other html/js trick?**

BTW *I'll downvote whoever will propose to*:

- change users
- force users to change browser
- ask me to render only visible cells and change server code

Comment: :) I'll give you a +1 when I'll meet you on a comic forum ! :)

Comment: I'm only joking, I am genuinely looking for an actual helpful answer! Wouldn't have been a smart ass if I was planning on not helping!

Comment: Yes, I know. So I've replied with ilarity. I thinked my ' :) ' was enough to make you understand I was laughing

Comment: How do you call function `selectText()` ? When you call it, filter element using  `:visible`, e.g `$('input:visible').selectText()`

Comment: I'm using `$('DIV.exportable_area').selectText()`. Your suggestion doesn't keep in mind the problem of hidden children elements. It's this the core of the question. But thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this question has been asked before multiple times. [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129613/hidden-text-can-be-selected-in-ie-despite-style-displaynone) - ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648148/dont-let-ie-select-and-copy-table-rows-that-are-hidden-using-jquery-hide))

It seems like there has not been a response that works fine for everyone.

You could use `is.(':visible')` in jQuery but not sure that translates back to javascript (not very good at it).

Other people have suggested cloning the table and only copying what's in the other table which is hidden, but then that causes a problem later on with other browsers which work fine.

You could use the above method which would work but it's a nasty hack.

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130156/2471423) which may be of interest to you, however I'm not sure what you're trying to copy and if this is worth the effort.

`<joke>`

If all else fails, here are some other recommendations:

- change users
- force users to change browser
- render only visible cells and change server code

`</joke>`

Answer (score 0):

Nasty hack, but you could:

- clone the table with js onload somewhere else on the page with a display:none
- 'Hiding' rows actually removes them from the DOM of the original table
- restoring hidden rows by replacing from hidden cloned version of table