# How to avoid IE to copy hidden elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

i have an mvc view where in i have hidden elements used and for other elements i have used display:none.but in i.e 9 when i right click and copy and paste that content in word it shows hidden elements as well.
kindly suggest some method so that i can make ie to copy only visible data not the hidden elements.
i searched google but not found a valid solution.
i have found other link but not useful:
[Html and Internet Explorer: How to avoid hidden elements to be copied/pasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601549/html-and-internet-explorer-how-to-avoid-hidden-elements-to-be-copied-pasted)

Comment: Unfortunately that answer pretty much sums it up. there are a few workarounds, but none of the workarounds are foolproof. Best bet would be to not have said hidden elements at that location.

Comment: didnt know if u ask a question and the person dont know the answer here they simply down vote.great hats off to your knowledge.

Comment: The answer is in the very question you linked to. this is a well known problem that has been well researched. All of the workarounds available are either in the answer you linked to, or linked to within that answer. I'm sorry of none of them are applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language. The reason it gets selected is because when you select in IE<9, you are not only selecting visible things but HTML in general. When you paste the copied data, it will show everything -because you copied the full HTML remember?- even the "display:none" elements.

The only real way i can think of, to prevent this behaviour is to not have hidden elements in the dom. At least not the elements you don't want to have copied.

**Computational purposes**

If the reason of hiding elements is, so you can use it to get data with jQuery or something else. You can use the trick from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130156/1474573